# How do I move multiple children from one node to another node in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need help with how to go about moving data from one node to the other. So, here is a screenshot of my database.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wLuh.jpg

I need to transfer data from the 'mastersheet' node to the 'events' node. You can ignore the part about adding the event name which is "Marathon" in this case.
You can safely assume that under the "mastersheet" node, the "Name" will always be at "2", the "email" at "3" and so on.

I know how to transfer individual children, but I'm not sure how to transfer multiple children especially by generating a push-id for each participant. Please help me out.

Here's the code that I have:

```
    DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("masterSheet"); //Open DBRef to raw data

 ref.addValueEventListener((new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                for(int i = 2; i<=5; i++)
                {
                    String val = data.child(String.valueOf(i)).getValue().toString();
                    String email = data.child("3").getValue().toString();

                    /*
                    Check if the email field is correct as that is very important
                     */
                    if(email.isEmpty() || !email.contains("@"))
                    {

                    }

                    else
                    {
                        switch(i){

                            /*
                            Based on the node, assign seperate column names and write in the appropriate values
                             */
                            case 2:
                                DatabaseReference Participants_name_ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Events").child(event_key).child("participants").child("Name");
                                Participants_name_ref.setValue(val);
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                DatabaseReference Participants_email_ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Events").child(event_key).child("participants").child("Email");
                                Participants_email_ref.setValue(val);
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                DatabaseReference Participants_CountryCode_ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Events").child(event_key).child("participants").child("Country Code");
                                Participants_CountryCode_ref.setValue(val);
                                break;
                            case 5:
                                DatabaseReference Participants_Phone_no_ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Events").child(event_key).child("participants").child("Phone Number");
                                Participants_Phone_no_ref.setValue(val);
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;




                        }
```

What this is doing is that, if there are 50 entries, it is only saving the Name, Email ID, Country Code and Phone number for the 50th entry and skipping the remaining 49.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to move data from a node to another, is the following. Because Firebase does not provide a magical `move()` method, you need to do it yourself and the flow is this:

1. Attach a listener on `mastersheet` node.
2. Loop on the `DataSnapshot` object to get all the childrens.
3. Get a reference of the `events` node.
4. Pass this object that contains the mastersheet data as an argument to the `setValue()` method and use that method directly on the reference.
5. Most important, don't forget to delete the data from the old location.